# Atribuir um valor numérico para um class html usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da memória e para isso preciso atribuir valores para as div onde serão armazenadas para comparar se as figuras selecionadas são iguais. Eu tentei desse modo (conforme código abaixo) mas não está funcionando. Alguém poderia me apontar o erro ou dar alguma dica do que eu posso fazer para funcionar?

Código JavaScript

```js
//Função para adicionar a imagem ao clicar
$('.peca').bind('click', function(){
 $(this).html('<img src="images/img1.jpg" border="0" height="100px"/>'); //Foi usado o parâmetro "this" para que ao clicar emm um objeto, somente este seja alterado
});

var p1 = $('.p1').attr('valor', 'numero[0]');
var p2 = $('.p2').attr('valor', 'numero[1]');
var p3 = $('.p3').attr('valor', 'numero[2]');
var p4 = $('.p4').attr('valor', 'numero[3]');
var p5 = $('.p5').attr('valor', 'numero[4]');
var p6 = $('.p6').attr('valor', 'numero[5]');
var p7 = $('.p7').attr('valor', 'numero[6]');
var p8 = $('.p8').attr('valor', 'numero[7]');
var p9 = $('.p9').attr('valor', 'numero[8]');
var p10 = $('.p10').attr('valor', 'numero[9]');
var p11 = $('.p11').attr('valor', 'numero[10]');
var p12 = $('.p12').attr('valor', 'numero[11]');
var p13 = $('.p13').attr('valor', 'numero[12]');
var p14 = $('.p14').attr('valor', 'numero[13]');
var p15 = $('.p15').attr('valor', 'numero[14]');
var p16 = $('.p16').attr('valor', 'numero[15]');

var numero = [16];

function numero_aleatorio () {
 var numero = [16];
 for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
  
  var ale = Math.floor(Math.random()*8+1); //Fuunção para gerar valores aleatórios de 1 a 8

  numero [i]=ale;

 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Jogo da Memória</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style type="text/css">
   .peca{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   .peca:hover{
    background-color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  
  <div class="tabuleiro">
   <div class="peca p1" valor=""></div> <!--Atribuindo uma class "valor" para fins de manipulação com javascript-->
   <div class="peca p2" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p3" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p4" valor=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div> <!--"Pular linha"-->
   <div class="peca p5" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p6" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p7" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p8" valor=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <div class="peca p9" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p10" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p11" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p12" valor=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <div class="peca p13" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p14" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p15" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p16" valor=""></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diego Soares, consegui resolver seu problema.
Primeiramente gostaria de apontar algumas coisas, você estava adicionando um atributo nas div's chamado `valor`, esse atributo não existe e isso não é uma boa pratica. Use data-value, fora isso tinha alguns problemas de sintaxe do javascript:
 1-  você estava atribuindo `var p1 = $('.p1').attr('valor', 'numero[0]');` o valor a uma variavél `p1`, e estava atribuindo o valor em aspas simples, não há necessidade.
2- Não precisava limitar seu array em 16 como você tinha feito, basta ir dando `array.push(valor)`.
Havia outros erros que não são tão importantes de se apontar e eu esqueci, segue abaixo o código funcionando.

```js
//Função para adicionar a imagem ao clicar
$('.peca').bind('click', function(){
 $(this).html('<img src="images/img1.jpg" border="0" height="100px"/>'); //Foi usado o parâmetro "this" para que ao clicar emm um objeto, somente este seja alterado
});

var numero = [];

function numero_aleatorio () {
 for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
  numero.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1));
 }
};

numero_aleatorio();

$('.p1').attr('data-value', numero[0]);
$('.p2').attr('data-value', numero[1]);
$('.p3').attr('data-value', numero[2]);
$('.p4').attr('data-value', numero[3]);
$('.p5').attr('data-value', numero[4]);
$('.p6').attr('data-value', numero[5]);
$('.p7').attr('data-value', numero[6]);
$('.p8').attr('data-value', numero[7]);
$('.p9').attr('data-value', numero[8]);
$('.p10').attr('data-value', numero[9]);
$('.p11').attr('data-value', numero[10]);
$('.p12').attr('data-value', numero[11]);
$('.p13').attr('data-value', numero[12]);
$('.p14').attr('data-value', numero[13]);
$('.p15').attr('data-value', numero[14]);
$('.p16').attr('data-value', numero[15]);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .peca{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   .peca:hover{
    background-color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
  </style>
  </head>

 <body>
  
  <div class="tabuleiro">
   <div class="peca p1" data-value=""></div> <!--Atribuindo uma class "valor" para fins de manipulação com javascript-->
   <div class="peca p2" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p3" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p4" data-value=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div> <!--"Pular linha"-->
   <div class="peca p5" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p6" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p7" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p8" data-value=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <div class="peca p9" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p10" valor=""></div>
   <div class="peca p11" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p12" data-value=""></div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <div class="peca p13" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p14" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p15" data-value=""></div>
   <div class="peca p16" data-value=""></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo Leonardo! Funcionou aqui. Só poderia me explicar por que a função tem que se chamada antes de atribuir os valores?

Comment: @DiegoSoares Porque a função é que da valor aleatório a cada posição do array, se você chamasse ela depois, não existiria valor dentro do array para inserir no data-value de cada div.